# Adding custom grails configuration helper methods?

Tags: grails, methods, configuration, groovy

I have a configuration parameter in my BuildConfig.groovy that requires I put a lot of directories in for each plugin I have.  I like to create a simple method that will generate all of those directories for me.  I know groovy config files are groovy code, but I can't seem to find any information related to the preferred method for creating helper methods. (for example mavenRepo, grailsPlugins(), grailsHome(), etc).  If I want to create my own helper method where would I put it so I can call it like so:

```
someProperty = myHelperMethod()
```

**A bit of an update**.  I wrote this method directly in my BuildConfig.groovy file and it works!  But I'd like to move it out and organize it better.  How do I write such methods and expose those to config files like BuildConfig.groovy?

```
def pluginDirs() {
   List dirs = []
   String trash = "[:]/"
   grails.plugin.location.each() { name, plugin ->
       if( plugin.startsWith(trash) ) {
           plugin = plugin.substring(trash.length())
       }
       dirs << "${plugin}/src/groovy" <<
               "${plugin}/grails-app/controllers" <<
               "${plugin}/grails-app/domain" <<
               "${plugin}/grails-app/services" <<
               "${plugin}/grails-app/taglib" <<
               "${plugin}/grails-app/utils"
   }
   return dirs
}
```

Extra-credit: Some of these plugins use ${basedir} to define their path, but when I run one of my scripts ${basedir} isn't defined to it puts [:] trash in my URLs.  That's why that ugly code is in there.

Comment: Grails don't export your Config.groovy when packaging the plugin. This is a fixed config for every plugin or it can be changed by the application?

Comment: ** Don't export,  unless you crate one with a custom name that ends with Config.groovy

Comment: This has nothing to do with externalizing configuration.  This is in BuildConfig.groovy.  I've gotten it working with the method I wrote defined in BuildConfig.groovy, but I wanted to know the "correct" way to do this.